# How to set DateTimeFormat for Epoch time in schema.ini?

Tags: c#, linq, oledb, datetime-format, oledbconnection

I have a Sybase database dump in pipe-delimited format that includes some columns in unix Epoch time format (the number of seconds since Jan. 1, 1970).  I am trying to read in the data using an OleDbConnection and have set up a schema.ini file.  The problem is that when I set a column in the schema.ini to DateTime, it shows nothing in the date columns, because it doesn't know how to parse it.

Is there a way to set the DateTimeFormat property in the schema.ini for an Epoch time?

Comment: Any reason you can't just read it as an `int` / `long` and then in your model property (or whatever) convert that to `DateTime`?

Comment: The issue is that I'm reading the data directly in to a DataTable and the columns of the DataTable are generated based on the entries in the schema.ini.  If I set the column to integer than I will have to change how I generate the DataTable.  If I have to do that, then I will.

Comment: Can you *add* a column to the `DataTable` rather than *modifying* the existing one? You could keep the existing generation, then go through the table populating the extra (`DateTime`) column based on the existing (`int`) column.